# How to remove Marker and redraw it again when changing location on Android map

Tags: android, dictionary, location, marker

////Before editing

I am using the below code to redraw a Marker on android map, actually it redraw a marker but it doesn't remove the old one, I tried

```
mapView.invlaidate
```

but it didn't remove the old one.

Here is the onLocationChanged function:

```
   @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // mapView.invalidate();

        //getCurrantPoint();
         OverlayItem currentOverlay = new OverlayItem(getCurrantPoint(),"Current Location","Here is my current location!!!");

            itemizedoverlay2.addOverlay(currentOverlay);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay2);
            mapOverlays.remove(currentOverlay);
            Log.v("TAG", "Removeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeed");

         ///
         //mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
 }
```

Thanks in Advance.

/////After editing

```
 if(itemizedoverlay2!=null)
     {
         mapOverlays.remove(itemizedoverlay2);

         itemizedoverlay2 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable2, cntxt);
         OverlayItem currentOverlay = new OverlayItem(getCurrantPoint(),"Current Location","Here is my current location!!!");
         itemizedoverlay2.addOverlay(currentOverlay);

         mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay2);
     }
     else
     {
            itemizedoverlay2 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable2, cntxt);

            OverlayItem currentOverlay = new OverlayItem(getCurrantPoint(),"Current Location","Here is my current location!!!");
            itemizedoverlay2.addOverlay(currentOverlay);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay2);

     }
```

Big thanks to imran khan and agarwal; I used your answers to debug the problem.

Comment: so finally solved your issue?

Comment: yes, and there is another issue appears - I want to calculate distance between two locations :)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
OverlayItem currentOverlay = new OverlayItem(getCurrantPoint(),"Current Location","Here is my current location!!!");
itemizedoverlay2.addOverlayItem(currentOverlay);
mapOverlays.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay2);
mapOverlays.getOverlays().remove(itemizedoverlay2);
mapOverlays.invalidate();
Log.v("TAG", "Removeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeed");
```

//mapOverlays is your mapView obejct and itemizedoverlay2 is your LocationOverlay

*remove LocationOverlay i.e itemizedoverlay2 instead of OverlayItem*

Comment: I tried this one but also nothing changed ... Actually I got a solution for this maybe it will work in another place, would you check it above in the question?

Answer (score 1):

try this:::

@Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // mapView.invalidate();

```
    //getCurrantPoint();
     OverlayItem currentOverlay = new OverlayItem(getCurrantPoint(),"Current Location","Here is my current location!!!");
        itemizedoverlay2.clear();
        itemizedoverlay2.addOverlay(currentOverlay);
       //in above line create new itemizedoverlay2 every time.
        mapOverlays.clear();
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay2);            

     ///
     //mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

}

Updated have a look:::

A typical custom overlay looks like this. it encapsulates the various OverlayItems displayed on the map in a list.

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

    private List<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));        
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public void removeOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.remove(overlay);
        populate();
    }


    public void clear() {
        mOverlays.clear();
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }
}
```

Methods can be exposed to add / remove individual overlayitems, but also the remove all overlayitems (clear method).

Remove a single overlayitem

```
MyItemizedOverlay sitesOverlay =  (MyItemizedOverlay ) map.getOverlays().get(0);
sitesOverlay.removeOverlay(overlay);
```

Add a single overlayItem

```
MyItemizedOverlay sitesOverlay =  (MyItemizedOverlay ) map.getOverlays().get(0);
sitesOverlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(p, "title", "snippet"));
```

Remove all overlayItems

```
MyItemizedOverlay sitesOverlay =  (MyItemizedOverlay ) map.getOverlays().get(0);
sitesOverlay.clear();
```

Comment: might be your location is same both times or create new instance of itemizedoverlay2

Comment: The location changed; It draws the new location but it keeps the old one too.

Comment: that is only i'm telling create new instance for itemizedoverlay2 or remove overlay from it before adding other

Comment: you are adding every time  itemizedoverlay2.addOverlay(currentOverlay); but before adding call itemizedoverlay2.clear():

Comment: I used your logic but with my beginner way like above ... I updated the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why to reinvent your own distance calculator, there is one built into the [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class.

Check out

```
distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
```

Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between them.

Comment: Do you have example how to use it properly because I tried distanceTo and distanceBetween but it return unknown data (to me)