# Show Overlay automatically without Tap on Marker in Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I am able to show a custom Overlay by clicking on the Marker on the Map. But how can I show this Overlay without clicking the Marker?!

Answer (score 0):

The following link provides you a solution for showing Overlay automatically without Tapping on Marker in maps

[How to remove Marker and redraw it again when changing location on Android map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258192/how-to-remove-marker-and-redraw-it-again-when-changing-location-on-android-map)